# JavaScript if/else statement returns with a logged answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function at the end of an jQuery animation. The function is being called before the animation and the function comes up with a logged answer. The function works perfectly fine first time but from the second time on it repeats a logged answer.

```js
var random_1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
var random_2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);

function result(){

 if (random_1 > random_2) {
  $("#result").html("A won");
  return;
 }

 else {
  $("#result").html("b won")
 }
}

$("#start").click(function(){
 $("#car_1").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_1,result());
 $("#car_2").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_2);
});

$("#reset").click(function(){
 $("#result").html("");
 $("#car_1").removeAttr("style");
 $("#car_2").removeAttr("style");
});
```

```css
img{
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
}

.track{
 background: url("https://i.imgur.com/BKL70mT.png") center;
 height: : 100px !important;
 margin-top: 2em;
}

#car_1, #car_2{
 position: relative;
}

#result{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: arial;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="track">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZxAEmIn.png" id="car_1">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nNIg2m4.png" id="car_2">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: put random_1 & 2 into result() to create a new number every call, not once at page load

Comment: You only generate the random numbers once. Check what the two random values are. You'll see they never change.

Comment: The first comment is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How can I generate it every time I the animation runs ?

Answer (score 1):

There is one reason that Result is repeat everytime. Like if first "A won" then you get that everytime because you did not generate new random value.

To do that you have to get random generation in side function.

```
var random_1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
var random_2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);

function result(){

    if (random_1 > random_2) {
        $("#result").html("A won");
        return;
    }

    else {
        $("#result").html("b won")
    }



}

$("#start").click(function(){
    $("#car_1").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_1,result());
    $("#car_2").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_2);

   random_1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
   random_2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
});

$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("#result").html("");
    $("#car_1").removeAttr("style");
    $("#car_2").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Comment: Should I have to place the result function inside the click event ?

Comment: That you can call after two animate function but before generating new random value.

Answer (score 1):

You can place everything within the "Start" click handler like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").click(function(){
    var random_1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
    var random_2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
    console.log("A: "+random_1);
    console.log("B: "+random_2);

    if (random_1 > random_2) {
      $("#result").html("A won");
        return;
    }else{
      $("#result").html("b won")
    }

    $("#car_1").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_1);
    $("#car_2").animate({"left":screen.width - 150},random_2);
  });

  $("#reset").click(function(){
      $("#result").html("");
      $("#car_1").removeAttr("style");
      $("#car_2").removeAttr("style");
  });
});
```

```css
img{
  position:relative;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button> <button id="reset">Reset</button><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<img id="car_1" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/car-256.png"><br>
<img id="car_2" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/car-xxl.png"><br>
```

As mentionned in comments, your issue was the random number creation made only once on page load. Now there are new numbers to compare at each "Start" click.

Now, the one who wins here is the one with the higher number... But it's the one who looks slower too! I would reverse that logic (in the condition). ;)